# JS RegEx to remove part of a URL?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the GoogleBooks API to search for particular titles by name and retrieve a cover image URL. For example, searching for "The Great Gatsby" will return the following image link:

http://books.google.com/books/content?id=HestSXO362YC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api

If you look at the following image, you can see that there is a small fold on the bottom right corner. Some image URLs will have the fold and others won't. If you remove `edge=curl` from the URL link, the fold is removed.

Is there any way to use a regex to find and delete the curled portion?

Further, is there any way to use regex to change the `img=1` value to `img=2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the ***.replace()*** method

```
let URL = "some random URL you have"
console.log(URL.replace('&edge=curl',''))
```

Will replace every **"&edge=curl"** that it finds in this string and replace it with **''** an empty string which is basically removing it.

You can also use the same method ***.replace()*** to replace any static URL variables like **"img=1"**

```
console.log(URL.replace('img=1','img=2'))
```

Comment: Thanks. Super new to all this, and this is very obvious in retrospect. Appreciate it.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as correct or upvote it to help future viewers of the question

Comment: Something to note is that this relies on the value of `img` being known before it's updated which may be tricky in some cases. This approach will updated the parameter regardless of the value in the input string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439323/js-regex-to-remove-part-of-a-url/59439430#59439430

Answer (score 1):

To obtain an updated url where the `&edge=curl` pattern is replaced and the `&img=` and `&zoom=` parameters are updated, you could achieve this by chaining multiple `.replace()` calls as shown below:

```js
const url = "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=HestSXO362YC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"

// New values for img and zoom parameters
const img = 300;
const zoom = 22;

console.log(
url
.replace(/&img=(\w+)/,`&img=${img}`)    
.replace(/&zoom=\w+/,`&zoom=${zoom}`)
.replace(/&edge=curl/,"")
)
```

Here the `&img=` and `&zoom=` parameters are updated with regular expressions `&img=\w+` and `&zoom=\w+`, where `\w+` will match one or more alpha numeric characters that appear after the parameter.

The advantage with this approach (over explicitly specifying `img=1` and replacing it with `img=2` ) is that you can update those parameter/value substrings of the input url without having to know the actual value of those parameters prior to replacement (ie that `img` has a value `1`).

Note that this approach assumes the parameters being updated are prefixed with `&` (and not `?`).

Hope that helps!

Comment: What if img is the first query string parameter e.g. `/content?img=asdf&id=fdsa`?

Comment: The edit makes it worse, it'll match `?ximg=123`! you could test for `(?|&)img=[^&]*`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex to parse URLs. Use [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object:

```js
var u = new URL("http://books.google.com/books/content?id=HestSXO362YC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api");

u.searchParams.delete("edge");
u.searchParams.set("img", "2");

console.log(u.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
let url = 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=HestSXO362YC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api';
// remove &edge=curl
url = url.replace('&edge=curl', '');
// replace img=1 with img=2
url = url.replace('img=1', 'img=2');
```